# How to profile tox?

Tags: python, profiling, tox

I run a particular test-case via tox:

```
tox -e myenv foo.tests.test_foo.SomeTestCase
```

This takes 30 seconds.

The test itself is very simple and fast. But there seem to be a lot happening before the
test starts to run.

How can I trace/profile the things which happen before the test runs?

Profiling only tox won't help I guess, because tox does not do much. Tox spawns subprocesses which take too long.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[tox 4](https://pypi.org/project/tox/4.0.0a9/) prints out timestamps as it does the job when passed two level of verbosity. So my advice is to install tox 4 and then do `tox -vvv r -e myenv --foo.tests.test_foo.SomeTestC`.

PS. A likely big you could do is by enabling wheel build over sdist builds (supported only in tox 4) as installing a sdist is very expensive currently with pip due to needing to set up an isolated build environment:

```
[testenv]
package = wheel
# below settings only applies if you don't have a c extension
wheel_build_env = .pkg
```

PS. I'm the tox author/maintainer.

Comment: Should that be `r` be a `-r` (to force recreating the virtual env)?

Comment: No, @Hugo  it's just r ☺️the r here is shortcut for the run subcommand ☺️ tox 4 longer tries to cram in everything under a single command 